# How to make Apache run another script after serving specific file types

Tags: apache-2.4

I am trying to find the best course of action to make Apache run a script before or after serving a file with a specific extension (or better, a predefined regular expression path).

To be more specific, I would like to get all requests to MP4 files on my server, to also trigger a short PHP script that gets the request URI, and sends it to an external logging service.

I am open to other similar alternative, but I wish to:

- Avoid the approach where it is needed to work on the Apache logs themselves, after the fact.
- Avoid having to stream the file through my script.

I have found [mod_action](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_actions.html) which seemed promising, but as far as I understand this serves a script *instead* of the actual file, not *in addition* to it.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: Did you try to specify a custom file [handler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/handler.html)? Documentation says: `The CGI script is responsible for sending the originally requested document (pointed to by the PATH_TRANSLATED environment variable) and making whatever modifications or additions are desired.` I don't know of any way to trigger a script in addition to serving the file, I think you have to intercept the process with a script and make the script to serve your file.

Comment: @GiedriusRekasius - thanks for that. I am familiar with handlers, although I never used them as I usually achieve similar functionality through rewrite rules. But, I wish to avoid having to stream the file through my script, as these may be large files.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a php script that served the file download (using headers ()) and log the download in that script. Similar to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615797/utility-of-http-header-content-type-application-force-download-for-mobile

Comment: Thanks, but I wish to avoid it. Since I am trying to just log the request to that file using an external logger, and since the files in questions are videos, I wish to avoid interfering with their natural delivery by Apache. I have updated the question to clarify this in case there is still a small chance that what I am looking for is possible...

Comment: I get it. I am unaware of any Apache hooks for such a thing. Just in case someone finds this via Google, I wrote a script on my lunch break that implements the method I described. http://pastebin.com/y7mk030r This will serve the file, unaltered.